# NSURLs for all video from Photo Album

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to make a custom app where I would like to display all of users videos from their photo album into a UITableView. The problem that I have is that I cannot figure out how can I get to all of the vidoes NSURLs. Once I have them I can put them in a NSArray and create a image from each of them and put them in the table. I am trying to do something similar as done with in this app. Any suggestions?

Please note I am familiar with UIImagePickerController to display images in a pop-up view controller. That's not what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

First add AssetsLibrary.framework

```
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
```

Then

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
 {
     [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop)
      {
          if (alAsset)
          {
              ALAssetRepresentation *representation =[alAsset defaultRepresentation];
              NSURL *url = [representation url];
              NSString *assetType=[alAsset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType];
              UIImage *thumbNailImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:alAsset.thumbnail];
          }
      }];
     if(group==nil)
     {
         // do what ever if group getting null
     }
 } failureBlock: ^(NSError *error)
 {
     // may be photo privacy setting disabled
 }
 ];
```

Comment: Can you please add the code for getting thumbnails as well? I will mark you answer correct. Thanks so much